# Box Shadow: different shadow in same div

Tags: html, css

I have a strange behaviour in my box shadow.

In my code I have this:

```
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px #d1d3da;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px #d1d3da;
box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px #d1d3da;
```

This works great, but when I add a background image for a header bar using

```
 background: #e7ebf4 url('http://imageshack.com/a/img673/4873/qv8bpR.png') repeat-x;
```

there is a difference in shadow.

An example can be found on 
http://jsfiddle.net/wouterdr/1txww2ps/

The part with the dark blue bar has a smaller / lighter shadow. The other part has a bigger shadow.

We would like to have the same shadow over the entire div (preferable the shadow next to the light blue part.

Thank you very much!

Comment: Please update your fiddle with the right background image. As it is now, we can't do anything with it because there's no bg image available.

Answer (score 0):

you can use two or more box-shadows separated with `,` like this:

```
-moz-box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px #d1d3da, 0 0 5px 2px #fff;
-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px #d1d3da, 0 0 5px 2px #fff;
box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px #d1d3da, 0 0 5px 2px #fff;
```

and also you can use inner box-shadow by adding `inset` at the end of syntax and create everything you want.(ie. `0 0 5px 2px #fff inset`)

Answer (score 0):

The shadow appears to be fine, but with repeat-x you'll only ever repeat horizontally. In order to repeat on both x and y axes just use "repeat" like so:

```
background: #e7ebf4 url('http://placehold.it/25x25') repeat;
```

FYI you can use http://placehold.it/100x100 for example to create an image on the fly, any size. Just change the dimensions so 200x200 works too, etc.

Comment: Thanks for your info. I saw that my latest changes weren't saved. Here is a new jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/wouterdr/1txww2ps/. I see really a different at the right (with the shadows)

Comment: I just updated that jsfiddle - I removed the break tags and added text content instead, then applied the shadow and rounding to the entire 'homeblock' div.

Comment: Make sure you remove the shadow from your bg image, it's making the 'homeblock' box shadow css look faded compared to the rest.